# Do all WebAPIs get pushed on the task queue?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I've watched Philip Roberts' presentation on the event loop ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf ) and I couldn't understand everything.

He says that WebAPIs don't get executed directly on the call stack, they get pushed inside this specific section for WebAPIs and then, when their timer is done ( if they have one ), they get pushed on the task queue. ( The talk about the event loop starts at 12:50 )

On https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API, I saw that `console` is also a WebAPI.

**Does `console.log()` also get pushed on the task queue, or do only WebAPIs that have a certain timer, just like `setTimeout` or wait for a certain event ( like a click event listener on a button in DOM ) get pushed on the task queue ?**

This is what I've tried so far to answer that question:

At minute 13:45 he says this:

> The  event loop job is to look at the stack and look at the task queue. If the stack is empty, it takes the first thing on the queue and pushed it on to the stack.

However, if I run this code:

```
console.log("log 1");

while(true){}

console.log("log 2");
```

I will get `log 1` in the console, and then the entire tab will be blocked because of the `while(true)` statement. Does that mean that `console.log()` is directly executed and it's not pushed on the task queue ? If it would be pushed on the task queue, then it would wait for the call stack to be empty, however, the call stack can't be empty because I have the `while(true)` statement in there that will run forever. The `console.log("log 1")` is still executed, even if `console` is a WebAPI. Does that mean that `console.log()` is not pushed on the task queue and only the WebAPIs that have a timer, like `setTimeout`, or wait for an event to trigger like `addEventListener` from the `DOM` WebAPI, get pushed on the task queue ?

Comment: while(true){} is blocking which would prevent console.log from executing. you only have to worry about the event loop for asynchronous tasks

Comment: @BrandonPina I understand that while(true) is blocking, but it doesn't stop the first console.log from executing. Does that mean that console.log() gets executed instantly, or does it get pushed on the task queue and gets executed when the call stack is empty ?

Comment: @BrandonPina The question was if all WebAPIs get pushed on the task queue. In this case I don't see console.log() getting pushed on the task queue ( I think ), even if it's a WebAPI

Comment: Does this help if we tell you that browsers are not written in JS, and that the event loop is not driven by JS, but that JS is only executed sometimes by tasks that are executed by the event-loop? Now, that this is cleared up, all WebAPIs calls don't post a new task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only asynchronous WebAPIs, like DOM Events, fetch, setTimeout, setInterval, etc. are pushed on the callback queue. Synchronous WebAPIs like console for example, are directly executed, without being enqueued on the callback queue.

Comment: I guess (and hope) there is an "events" missing after "DOM".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. DOM is a WebAPI, you can look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API. I think that all the asynchronous methods inside the DOM API are pushed on the callback queue. I don't think that a method like ```getElementById``` would be pushed on the callback queue. I think that ```addEventListener``` would be pushed on the callback queue since that's asynchronous

Comment: ... see how it's not called "the DOM API" but just "the DOM"? The DOM is not an API, it's a model that does define some Interfaces that other APIs will use or that defines APIs. For instance it does define various Event APIs. If one were to say "the DOM API" what would be colloquially understood is the Document+Element+Node APIs (all `getElement...` etc. methods). And these don't post tasks (they do indirectly trigger microtasks to be queued but that becomes complex). So if you want to talk about the ones that queue tasks, better call it "DOM events" directly.